# Correct way of storing and retreiving an external storage path as preference

Tags: android

I want to ask the app user for a path where the app is supposed to store some files, this should be stored in the preferences so I can access this directory at all times. Currently, I request the folder through an intent, then store the URI as a String and when I write a file I convert the string back to an URI and use `fromTreeUri` to create the file (code snippets below).

This works until I restart the app. Then I get an error:

```
W/DocumentsContract: Failed to create document
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{92157d9 9222:xxxx} (pid=9222, uid=10310) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I know this is because of the permission system, but I cannot find the matching documentation on how this is supposed to be used. I know other apps have this feature and they do not request user confirmation on each app start.

Obtaining the diretory URI:

```kotlin
private fun selectDirectory(){
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), REQUEST_TARGET_FOLDER)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_TARGET_FOLDER -> {
            if (data == null || data.data == null || data.data == Uri.EMPTY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Invalid URI, got intent $data with data ${data?.data}")
                return
            } else {
                val targetDir = data.data.toString()
                val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
                sharedPref.edit().putString(
                    resources.getString(R.string.settings_storage_directory),
                    targetDir
                ).apply()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the document within a function in the activity:

```kotlin
// this is the Activity, baseDir the value from the preferences as string
val file = "test.jpg"
val mime = "image/jpeg"
val document =  DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, Uri.parse(baseDir))?.createFile(mime, file)
```

How is this done correctly?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: You should take persistable uri permission in onActivityResult in order to use the obtained uri later on.

Comment: Nice, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from CommonsWare and blackapps I was able to fix it:

```kotlin
private fun selectDirectory(){
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)

    // This line for requesting persistable URI permissions
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), REQUEST_TARGET_FOLDER)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_TARGET_FOLDER -> {
            if (data == null || data.data == null || data.data == Uri.EMPTY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Invalid URI, got intent $data with data ${data?.data}")
                return
            } else {

                // This line for taking the persistable URI permissions
                contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(data.data!!, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION + Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

                val targetDir = data.data.toString()
                val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
                sharedPref.edit().putString(
                    resources.getString(R.string.settings_storage_directory),
                    targetDir
                ).apply()
            }
        }
    }
}
```